# Having an issue when reassigning a value according to my csv file

Tags: flutter, dart, csv, intellij-idea

So I am making a game which is text based. How it works is there's a csv file which contains a few integer values and a description. For example:

`1,2,8,9,You wake up in your village for another regular day. Do you go for a morning walk?`

When I click my yes button, the program progresses as it should. However, when i click no or maybe, the program progresses to the next situation as it should, however, the buttons then become unresponsive and the program crashes.

I am utilising a Hive database which I believe is set up properly.

Below is the code I have set up for the event handlers.

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      //PLACE CODE HERE YOU WANT TO EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY AFTER
      //THE UI IS BUILT
      setState(() {
        //1,3,You are at the entrance of a maze
        Node? current = box.get(1);
        if(current != null) {
          iD = current.iD;
          yesID = current.yesID;
          maybeID = current.maybeID;
          noID = current.noID;
          description = current.description;
        }

      } );
    });
  }

  void buttonHandlerYes(){
    setState(() {
      Node? nextNode = box.get(yesID);
      if (nextNode != null) {
        iD = nextNode.iD;
        yesID = nextNode.yesID;
        maybeID = nextNode.maybeID;
        noID = nextNode.noID;
        description = nextNode.description;
      }
    });
  }

  void buttonHandlerMaybe(){
    setState(() {
      Node? nextNode = box.get(maybeID);
      if (nextNode != null) {
        iD = nextNode.iD;
        yesID = nextNode.yesID;
        maybeID = nextNode.maybeID;
        noID = nextNode.noID;
        description = nextNode.description;
      }
    });
  }

  void buttonHandlerNo(){
    setState(() {
      Node? nextNode = box.get(noID);
      if (nextNode != null) {
        iD = nextNode.iD;
        yesID = nextNode.yesID;
        maybeID = nextNode.maybeID;
        noID = nextNode.noID;
        description = nextNode.description;
      }
    });
  }
```

I've tried messing around with the event handlers but I'm not really sure what I am doing!